# Composer fails to install laravel/socialite 2.0

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-socialite, guzzle

**composer require laravel/socialite ^2.0**

is failing with below error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/socialite 2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2.2
    - laravel/socialite v2.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 6.2.2].
    ...
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.4, 6.2.2].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 6.2.2) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Laravel version is 5.3.22

PHP version is 7.0.10

The [composer.json of socialite2.0](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/composer.json) on github shows the dependency as guzzlehttp 5.0/ 6.0.  Why's my install looking for guzzlehttp 4.0?

**EDIT-1:**

I tried to force guzzlehttp 4.2.4 by adding it in composer.json require-dev.

However, I received following error:

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 6.2.2, required as 4.2.4) is satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 3.19.23 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^5.3.1|^6.2.1 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.x-dev, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.3.0, 6.2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 3.19.23 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^5.3.1|^6.2.1 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.x-dev, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.3.0, 6.2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 3.19.23 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^5.3.1|^6.2.1 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.x-dev, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.3.0, 6.2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for aws/aws-sdk-php (locked at 3.19.23) -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.19.23].
```

Apparently, aws-sdk-php requires guzzlehttp 5.3/ 6.2.  Laravel 5.3 is not compatible with socialite 3.0.  Socialite 2.0 is not compatible with guzzlehttp 5.3/ 6.2.

How to resolve this?

TIA

**EDIT-2:**

my composer.json has below content:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your composer.json file?

Comment: One possibility is install at old version of aws/aws-sdk-php for example 2.8 version of this package

Comment: Another solution is update your laravel version to 5.3 at 5.4, your system supported requisites. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/composer.json

Comment: @ThomasEdwards, I posted composer.json.  adding `guzzlehttp 4.2.4` to `require-dev` revealed aws-sdk-php dependency.  upgrading Laravel version or downgrading aws-sdk-php requires lot of effort, to validate the application.  Unfortunately, that's not an option..

Comment: BTW, my primary requirement is to allow users to post photos to FB/Twitter/G+ from our website (NOT the links).  Is there any alternative available to achieve this?

Comment: Now, and a few minutes, i have a idea. Exists a file that its name is composer.lock. Can you remove this file and folder vendor, and try to launch again the command: "composer require laravel/socialite ^2.0"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how the issue got resolved:  It turned out to be simple.  As I'm still learning what composer can do, I couldn't figure it out earlier.

Changing from `^` to `~` in the version did the trick.  As per [Mastering Composer - tips & tricks](https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-composer-tips-tricks/), both tilde (`~`) & caret (`^`) should allow minor versions in the packages.  But, it appears "*only be careful of breaking changes*" took the precedence over allowing minor versions. (at least, that's the conclusion I arrived at).

Following is the result:

```
composer require laravel/socialite:~2.0
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing league/oauth1-client (1.7.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing laravel/socialite (v2.0.21): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
```

Answer (score 2):

I have one idea of this problem.

In `composer.lock`, save a hash and version of package that you download with your composer config, in this moment or an another time. Then delete this file and vendor folder and execute again:

```
composer require laravel/socialite ^2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : composer require laravel/socialite:~2.0
It Work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

add `"laravel/socialite": "2.*"` in `composer.json` then run

`composer update`

and

`composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

Hope it will help.

See: [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/socialite).

Comment: this comand download 3.0 version of socialite, but @krsna want 2.0v,

And socialite 3.0 version required minimum 5.4v of Laravel. This not a option and solution

Comment: Version doesn't  matter it will work properly. I think he has little confusion if he download latest version then code will not work